DiscordBot not answering
I can't understand why my Discord Bot is not responding or messaging to me.
I had written the the correct code and also set my token correct and my code was:
import discord
import os


TOKEN = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# Initialize the bot client
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged on as {client.user}!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignore messages from the bot itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Respond to a specific command (e.g., "!hello")
    if message.content.lower() == "!hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hello, world!")

    # Add more custom commands or logic here

# Run the bot
client.run(TOKEN)

and on the out put it also showed logged on but at last I can't get the solution of my problem.
I thought that it if I reset my token then it will be ok, but no, I think this is the fault of setting my discord bot because all yt tutorial I got is old as 1 to 2 year and discord developer portal had updated. I also checked the permission of my bot too. But can't get the solution.
Although I was in the the replit and also set the secret.

Hi and welcome on stackoverflow, does this answer your question ?
